# reading strings in c++, compiling in c++

Tags: c++, string, compilation

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <istream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::string color, pluralNoun, celebrity;

    std::cout << "enter a color: ";
    std::getline(cin, color);  
    std::cout << "enter a plural noun: ";
    std::getline(cin, pluralNoun);
    std::cout << "enter a celebrity: ";
    std::getline(cin, celebrity);

    cout << "Roses are " << color << endl;
    cout << pluralNoun << "are blue" << endl;
    cout << "I love " <<celebrity <<endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Hallo developers..

To keep it short: I come from Java ..

is that enough? I already had enormous problems with reading the strings, and had to search about 50 pages for needed libraries. In addition, I have included in a statement the namespace std, and yet I get an error message when I remove std before the cout s.

```
"ConsoleApplication3.exe" (Win32): "D:\Users\nils\source\repos\ConsoleApplication3\Debug\ConsoleApplication3.exe" geladen. Symbole wurden geladen.
"ConsoleApplication3.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll" geladen. Symbole wurden geladen.
"ConsoleApplication3.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll" geladen. Symbole wurden geladen.
"ConsoleApplication3.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll" geladen. Symbole wurden geladen.
"ConsoleApplication3.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140d.dll" geladen. Symbole wurden geladen.
"ConsoleApplication3.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll" geladen. Symbole wurden geladen.
"ConsoleApplication3.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll" geladen. Symbole wurden geladen.
Der Thread 0x4d6c hat mit Code -1073741510 (0xc000013a) geendet.
Der Thread 0x4dc8 hat mit Code -1073741510 (0xc000013a) geendet.
Der Thread 0x486c hat mit Code -1073741510 (0xc000013a) geendet.
Das Programm "[2132] ConsoleApplication3.exe" wurde mit Code -1073741510 (0xc000013a) beendet.
```

Can anyone explain why this does not work, and if there are other ways to read the strings? As far as I can read consoles all required files were loaded (for the pdb file I used the visual studio server, dll I saved locally. (sry for the debugger, i am german, "geendet" means that it finished, not that there are any problems)

- Nils Drees -

Comment: This is English speaking site, your error messages are unreadable, can you switch your IDE temporarily to produce errors in English?

Comment: You should get int he habit of avoiding `using namespace std;`. It can lead to problems later on.

Comment: Your error messages are not readable. Please make it English.

Comment: And please explain what "does not work" mean

Comment: Did you use Ctrl+C to end the program? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45691954/native-exiting-with-with-code-1073741510-0xc000013a-while-using-prime-checke) indicates that is what the exit code means.

Comment: I don't see any issues that a few `std::endl;`s won't fix: https://ideone.com/advng3

Comment: When I googled for `0xc000013a` it said you pressed ctrl-c or forcibly closed the command window.

Comment: The errors aren't in the code (although it's a bit of a mess). The error must be in the way you are using your compiler. Hard to help with that, but you're doing something fundamentally wrong.

Comment: The first messages are not relevant - it's just VS complaining about missing symbols. The rest means that the program exited with `0xc000013a`. As @drescherjm pointed out, the command window was probably closed and OP mistook that output for errors. He probably did not input the 3 lines his program expects.

Comment: I say all of the current answers are wrong. ***Das Programm "[2132] ConsoleApplication3.exe" wurde mit Code -1073741510 (0xc000013a) beendet.*** says that the program compiled and ran. It also says the user either closed the window or pressed ctrl+c.

Answer (score 1):

If you just started learning c++ and using Visual Studio i would recommend that you create your project in this manner :
[image: Chosse Empty Project]

As the option says it'll create an empty project where you'll have to manually add header and cpp files in those:

[image: Just right click on the folder and select Add -> Add New Item]

Header file should go to the Header Folder and cpp file to the Source folder.

The problem you encountered was because when you created your new project you selected "Windows Console Application", by default Visual Studio will create the project including the pre-compiled header named "pch.h".

This header is useful in a bit larger projects, basically you should include in "pch.h" headers you will use very often in multiple files like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
```

etc...
And then you should include "pch.h" in cpp file at the very top.

Warning tho, this is not even the basics of the topic, but if you're only starting and trying things out i think it's going to be easier to deal with an empty project, but for later do some research on pre-compiled headers, they're very useful.

Also as other mentioned, try to avoid

```
using namespace std;
```

as much as possible

Hope this will help you for later.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @"Radu Z". You were almost rigth: the problem was, that the header had to be used, i do not know why, but it had to be empty, and I also do not know where this makes sense, but it worked for me to delete the lines concerning the namespace, leaving me with:

```
#ifndef PCH_H
#define PCH_H


// TODO: add headers

#endif //PCH_H
```

I am very grateful that you all answered that quickly, and I promise to change my Language to english for the next questions. Concerning the namespace, I removed it since I had to use the stds anyway.

Comment: This is because you have precompiled headers enabled in your project. For small projects that don't have many external includes its best to turn that off. With that said this could not have been related to any issue you had because your program wouldn't have built if you did not have the `pch.h` file. You could not execute it at all. Unless you pressed debug anyways (and somehow had an old exe in the same folder of the same name) on the failure to compile I don't see how this could have been the problem.

Answer (score -1):

First, I deleted the first line of your code, which is

```
#include "pch.h"
```

, as I didn't have that file and it compiled. Maybe you don't have that file either. Then, I put a space before "are blue", so the plural noun and the "are blue" aren't connected.

```
cout << pluralNoun << " are blue" << endl;
```

And it all worked perfectly.
Maybe your problem is the compiler you use? I can't decipher your errors but my opinion is that you should check the pch.h file and the compiler.

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: `#include "pch.h"` means the user is likely using Visual Studio with precompiled headers enabled. If you have this default setting enabled and don't include `pch.h` at the top of every source file you get an error message.

Comment: ***I can't decipher your errors*** There really was only 1 message that was important. **Das Programm "[2132] ConsoleApplication3.exe" wurde mit Code -1073741510 (0xc000013a) beendet** The rest was normal for any program.

Answer (score -1):

From your question I assume you are using **Visual Studio**. 
You should always have the first include line

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

or

```
#include "pch.h"
```

as introduced recently. [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51928685/can-i-use-include-pch-h-instead-of-include-stdafx-h-as-my-precompile-heade).

Then go to 
**Project -> Properties** 
and then to 
**C/C++ -> Precompiled Headers**

In the first setting: **Precompiled Header** select **Create (/Yc)**

In the second setting: **Precompiled Header File** select **stdafx.h**

In the third setting: **Precompiled Header Output File** select **$(IntDir)$(TargetName).pch**

This is in fact where you define your .pch file.

Comment: I believe newer versions of Visual Studio by default look for  `pch.h` instead of `stdafx.h`

Comment: Good to know. I am using VS2017 and haven't noticed, but I may be mistaken. In any case, the solution to the problem is in the Precompiled Header section of the Project's properties.

Comment: There is no requirement to use precompiled headers, as this answer implies. The issue cannot possibly be caused by an issue with precompiled headers either. Those issues result in compile errors. Clearly, the OP was able to compile the application, since they managed to run it.

Comment: This is best practice to always use precompiled headers, however step 2 can be changed so the compiler doesn't use precompiled headers.

Comment: Unconditionally using precompiled headers is certainly not *"best practice"*. There are reasons to use precompiled headers, and there are reasons to *not* use precompiled headers. You have to make a judicious decision. Irrespective, the OP's code compiles, so trying to fix a compiler error that does not exist doesn't help the OP solve *their* problem.

Comment: I completely disagree but thank you for your comment!