# After defining a function in another file, visual studio does not recognize the function

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm creating windows console app that has many pages (split in files). I'm facing a problem when executing the program and Visual Studio throws `'startpage' identifier not found` error (startpage is the function and the file name is startpage.h)

I've tried using:
`external int startpage();` and
`int startpage();`.
I've tried changing only the function name too (so the file and function don't use the same name).

I have no idea why this is happening. Other files with different functions are working. The file "startpage.h" uses two functions defined in other files, and those are not throwing any errors.

````
#include "include/startpage.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "include/concol.h"
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    startpage(); 
}

```
````

Here is the error:

```
Error code: C3861: 'startpage' identifier not found
```

Comment: it would help if you posted the contents of startpage.h

Comment: Move `#include "pch.h"` to the top. The compiler ignores everything above the inclusion of precompiled header.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Wait is that for real? I mean I believe you I just never knew this. Have you got a good source for this, alls I found was [this +2 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52640985/4143855)

Comment: Yes he is correct. Visual Studio ignores all lines above `#include "pch.h"` Or whatever the precompiled header is named.

Comment: Here is a link to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/yu-use-precompiled-header-file?view=vs-2019 ***The compiler treats all code occurring before the .h file as precompiled. It skips to just beyond the #include directive associated with the .h file, uses the code contained in the .pch file, and then compiles all code after filename.***

Comment: I am sure there is a duplicate for this however I have not found it.

Answer (score 0):

> Move #include "pch.h" to the top. The compiler ignores everything above the inclusion of precompiled header. – Igor Tandetnik

This worked!
Thank you so much guys!